# Ethernet network disconnected - wireless working

Tags: networking

I experience a problem after a I moved in to my new home. I connect to internet through a router. Wireless is working just fine, but wired network is disconnected (ofcourse I plugged in the cable) :). I experienced this problem in other distros also. In Windows it is working (not advertising).

Please help!

Comment: Is the network icon in the taskbar detecting your LAN?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

1. Get your IP address, Subnet Mask, Gateway & DNS from your Windows PC.
2. Assume that it is `192.168.0.101`, `255.255.255.0`, `192.168.0.1` & `8.8.8.8` from your windows pc.
3. Now replicate all this settings into your Ubuntu wired network. Of course you have to change the IP address to something else e.g. `192.168.0.102` to avoid IP conflict.
4. If you are able to connect now, then it could be something wrong with your router DHCP server when it tries communicating with Ubuntu, vice versa. There are a few times I have experienced this and by rebooting all devices at once it works again.

Comment: I allready tried this. It doesn't work! Thanks!

Comment: 1) Can the wired network connect once but then disconnect or cannot connect at all?
2) can you show `ipconfig`?